# Using an input string in a file path for a input vector layer in QGIS model

Tags: qgis, string, file-path, input

I am building a QGIS model to perform field calculations on a large number of .shp files containing environmental information of different waterbodies. This model should be global for the different waterbodies I am working with where one model run is performed for each waterbody. The waterbodies are specified in the filenames of the .shp files as a two-letter code (e.g., VF = Vejle Fjord).

The field calculator operations are getting input vector layers from an input folder containing the .shp files following a file path below:

> C:/Users/lees/OneDrive - Syddansk Universitet/Projects/QGIS Projects/GradientAnalysisModel/GIS_files/Model_input/GSmax_EN_VF_B.shp

My question is: Can I use a string input in the model builder to specify the waterbody code I want to use for the model and replace the waterbody code in the file paths used in the field calculators as below? This is so that I can specify which waterbody I use as input by typing the waterbody code in the model execution window.

Original file path:

> C:/Users/lees/OneDrive - Syddansk Universitet/Projects/QGIS Projects/GradientAnalysisModel/GIS_files/Model_input/GSmax_EN_VF_B.shp

Replaces file path using string input called WB_code:

> C:/Users/lees/OneDrive - Syddansk Universitet/Projects/QGIS Projects/GradientAnalysisModel/GIS_files/Model_input/GSmax_EN_@WB_code_B.shp